# XAMPP can't run my Manage Server

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I am totally new in the web development, I am using Mac OSX. and I am using XAMPP version 5.6.32. I just want to follow along the tutorial, but the I am stuck at the very first step.

[image]

I have tried to tap the 'Start All' button, but it is not running, MySQL Database, ProFTPD and Apache Web Server always stop.

when I open phpMyAdmin, it is said

[image]

what should I do ? I have no idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating XAMPP to the newest version (reinstall)... If it still doesn't work check what the Application log tab on the right says.